# Getting the outbound phonenumber in Android

Tags: android

Bellow a simplified piece of my code is shown. The important part is that I now have phone number when the call state is CALL_STATE_RINGING and the call is inbound. Now I also want the phone number when the call is outbound (so the phone number on the receiving end). What am I missing here?

```
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number) {
    Log.d("BackgroundService", "State: "+  state +" Number: " + number);
}

telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: you mean you want to know the number of outgoing call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a broadcast receiver using ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL. In the onReceive callback function you will know the number of outgoing call

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String phone = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }
```

And offcourse use the permission `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`